# Listar 3 Capas c# SQL SERVER Window Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenos Dias.
Estoy realizando un formulario que es para registrar un usuario lo estoy realizando en el lenguaje c# con 3 capas y base de datos SQL SERVER.

En mi Formulario para registrar tengo este aspecto como la imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podran Observar en mi formulario tengo 5 combobox .
El problema es que yo quiero que ese combobox se muestre dinamicamente con un procedimiento .

Este es el Procedimiento que utilizo para muestre mi procedimiento

```
Create procedure listarviaincidencia

@opt int,

as

if @opt =1

begin

SELECT DerivarA =   REPLICATE('0',2 - LTRIM(RTRIM(LEN(DerivarID)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DerivarID AS CHAR(2)))) + ' - ' +
                                UPPER(CAST(DerivarA AS VARCHAR(150)))
        FROM TAteDerivarA
        ORDER BY DerivarID

end
```

Este es el codigo de mis capas:

Capa Datos :

```
public class Cls_Conexion
{
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.105.150\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DBProAuxQP;User Id=sa;Password=DBServ@14;");

    //Metodo para abrir la conexion

    void abrir_conexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conexion.Open();
        }
    }

    //Cerrar la Conexion 

    void cerrar_conexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }

    //Metodo para ejecutar los Procedimientos  (Insert,delete,Update)

    public void Ejecutar_sp(String NombreSp, List<Cls_Parametro> lst)
    {
        SqlCommand  cmd;

        try
        {
            abrir_conexion();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(NombreSp,conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (lst != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                { 
                    //Verificar el Tipo de Entrada
                    if (lst[i].Direccion == ParameterDirection.Input)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(lst[i].Nombre, lst[i].Valor);
                    }

                    //Verificando el Tipo de Salida
                    if (lst[i].Direccion == ParameterDirection.Output)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(lst[i].Nombre, lst[i].TipoDato, lst[i].Tamaño).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    }

                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Recuperando los valores de Salida

                for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cmd.Parameters[i].Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
                    {
                        lst[i].Valor = cmd.Parameters[i].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        cerrar_conexion();
    }

    public DataTable Listado(String Nombresp, List<Cls_Parametro> lst)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        try
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(Nombresp, conexion);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (lst != null)
            { 
                for(int i=0; i<lst.Count;i++)
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(lst[i].Nombre, lst[i].Valor);
                }
            }
            da.Fill(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Mi capa Negocio :

```
public class Cls_RegistrarIncidencia
{



    /* Variables para Combobox ViaIncidencia */

    public int VI_Ope { get; set; }
    public string VI_Buscar { get; set; }

    Cls_Conexion M = new Cls_Conexion();



    public DataTable ListadoViaIncidencia()
    {

        List<Cls_Parametro> lst = new List<Cls_Parametro>();
        try
        {
            return M.Listado("PE_Ate_InformacionAtencion_New", lst);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

Mi Capa Presentacion en el LOAD donde quiero que ese combobox almacene los datos

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       RI.VI_Ope = 6;
        RI.VI_Buscar = "";



     DataTable dt =  RI.ListadoViaIncidencia();
     CboViaIncidencia.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ejecuto me sale un error en el dt. quisiera que me ayuden soy nuevo en c# no se si esta es la manera correcta para hacer en 3 capas.

Comment: Creo que te falto asignarle al combobox las propiedades de ValueMember y el DisplayMember.

Comment: valumenber en ves datasource para que llene de una consulta de sql server

Comment: No, el datasource esta bien, solo que necesitas especificarle al combobox que valor va a mostrar, por ejemplo tu estas regresando un datatable, y tiene 2 columnas nValor y aValor, entonces a parte del datasource solo necesitas asignarle el valor de estas columnas a tu combo.
    combo.ValueMember = "nValor";
    combo.DisplayMember = "aValor";

Comment: @Migue pero esos combobox se tienen que jalar de la base de datos 
en mi script solo es un select*from

Comment: @Migue como podrias observar en mi script es un solo campo

Comment: Si es un solo dato, solo pon el DisplayMember, te anexare un ejemplo como respuesta.

Comment: @Pierro podrías formular correctamente tu pregunta, debido a que tu procedimiento que indicas (tiene errores de sintáxis) y el procedimiento `PE_Ate_InformacionAtencion_New` difiere en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

te falta un pequeño fragmento de código en tu capa de negocios:

```
RI.VI_Ope = 6;
RI.VI_Buscar = "";
DataTable dt =  RI.ListadoViaIncidencia();
CboViaIncidencia.DataSource = dt;
CboViaIncidencia.DisplayMember = "nombre_columna_mostrar";
CboViaIncidencia.ValueMember = "nombre_columna_Valor";
```

Comment: Jeremy le puse y me salio este error:

No se puede enlazar con el nuevo miembro de presentación.

Comment: Puedes colocar el nombre del campo de la base de datos que deseas mostrar, que tipo es [varchar, int, etc] y el nombre de la columna que quieres que sea valor?

Comment: es un varchar :


SELECT DerivarA =   REPLICATE('0',2 - LTRIM(RTRIM(LEN(DerivarID)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(DerivarID AS CHAR(2)))) + ' - ' +
                                UPPER(CAST(DerivarA AS VARCHAR(150)))
        FROM TAteDerivarA
        ORDER BY DerivarID

Comment: Intenta esto: `RI.VI_Ope = 6;
RI.VI_Buscar = "";
DataTable dt =  RI.ListadoViaIncidencia();
CboViaIncidencia.DataSource = dt;
CboViaIncidencia.DisplayMember = "DerivarA";` No le coloques el value member

Comment: Sale como la foto que subi doctor.

Comment: ¿Estás consultado bien a la base de datos?, en tu código el nombre del SP es `listarviaincidencia`  pero en tu código lo llamas como `PE_Ate_InformacionAtencion_New`

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que hacer lo siguiente, en mi caso usare una lista.

```
public class Datos {
     public int nDato { get; set; }
     public string aDato { get; set; }
}

List<Datos> datos = new List<Datos>();
datos.Add(new Datos { nDato = 1, aDato = "Valor 1" });
datos.Add(new Datos { nDato = 2, aDato = "Valor 2" });
datos.Add(new Datos { nDato = 3, aDato = "Valor 3" });
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "aDato"; // valor que se mostrara en la dista desplegable
// si observas, tiene que ser el mismo nombre del dato que quiero mostrar en la lista
comboBox1.ValueMember = "nDato"; // y este seria el valor que tiene el elemento
comboBox1.DataSource = datos;  // en tu caso es un datatable, funciona igual con la lista
```

- Nota, tu me comentas que solo tienes un dato en tu DataTable, entonces como sera el valor a mostrar solo usarías el DisplayMember y el ValueMember estará en vació.
  ¿Para que te sirve el ValueMember? Te sirve por si quieres saber que valor del elemento seleccionado de tu combo y cargar combos en cascada o guardar el valor de ese elemento en la base de datos.

Saludos.

Comment: eso lo implemento en mi cada datos ?

Comment: en tu capa de presentación, antes de esta linea CboViaIncidencia.DataSource = dt; pones el 
CboViaIncidencia.DataMember = "nombre_de_tu_columna";

Comment: no me funciono :(

Comment: Te sigue mostrando lo mismo?

Comment: estas poniendo CboViaIncidencia.DataMember = "DerivarA"; ? ya que ese es el nombre de tu columna de tu consulta, no?

Comment: @Migue tu respuesta más parece una recomendación que la solución en si al problema.

Comment: @Davlio en realidad es la solución, si no lo crees, copia y pega el código :), ¿porque dices que es más una recomendación?

Comment: El código que pones (_como recomendación_) solo es para el caso que pones como ejemplo. Más bien, la pregunta está mal formulada. fíjate en el nombre de los procedimientos almacenado, en su definición (tiene errores) y la que envía en capa Negocio. *Son diferentes, la pregunta no esta clara.*

Comment: @Migue más bien te invito a [reportarlo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) porque no está claro lo que pregunta.

Comment: jaja es cierto, no había observado eso @Davlio el nombre del procedimiento no tiene nada que ver son su consulta. +1

Comment: @Davlio  me cerraron la pregunta :(